# layout changes when value is transferred ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On one page: I get "id" using Javascript and pass value through Ajax POST, and I get value using PHP. But the entire layout breaks down(the whole site is duplicated inside) and foreach php from bd also.

How to localize this conclusion? (for example data-id="56")(we are on `index.php` and we need to receive post request without refreshing whole page directly to the `$_POST['art_id']`)

```
<div>
  <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>">Button</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('div a').click(function() {
  $.post({   
    url: "index.php",  
    data: 'art_id=' + $(this).attr('data-id'),
    success: function(data){
      $("#result").append(data);
    },
  })
}
```

Current result(we get post_data: 56):

```
<div id="result"></div>
  <?php 
    $post_id = $_POST['art_id']; 
    echo 'post_data: '.$post_id; 
  ?>
```

I don't need to output the result in the div. Here's roughly what I want to get:

Needed result:

```
  <?php 
    $post_id = $_POST['art_id']; 
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$post_id'");
  ?>
```

I just need to pass post result into sql request.
But I don't understand how to rework this part:

```
success: function(data){
          $("#result").append(data);
        },
```

[Click on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/993Qc.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edyge.jpg)

Comment: what does `singers-redo.php"` return? that's what is put into `<div id="result"></div>`

Comment: Where is the `#result` div? You have one in the response, which will presumably end up in duplicated `id` attributes when if this code worked.

Comment: Added two pictures. when we click on the button, we get the div id(it's from bd), everything is sent, but the whole inner part is updated and php cycle doesn't update.

Comment: Updated post with needed result and replaced `singers-redo.php` with `index.php`. In our case, the logic page is like in `index.php` (we have a lot of code etc.)